# Convert Notepad++ Regex to PHP Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to convert a Notepad++ Regex to a PHP regular expression which basically get IDs from a list of URL in this format:

```
http://www.example.com/category-example/1371937-text-blah-blah-blah-2012.html
http://www.example.com/category-example/1471337-text-blah-blah-2-blah-2010.html
```

Using Notepad++ regex function i get the output that i need in two steps (a list of comma separated IDs)

(.*)/ replace with space

-(.*) replace with comma

Result:
    1371937,1471337

I tried to do something similar with PHP preg_replace but i can't figure how to get the correct regex, the below example removes everything except digits but it doesn't work as expected since there can be also numbers that do not belong to ID.

```
$bb =   preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', ',', $_POST['Text']);

?>
```

Which is the correct structure?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us an example of the pattern you are trying to match on, ie a sample from the list.

Comment: `http://www.example.com/category-example/1371937-text-blah-blah-blah-2012.html`
`http://www.example.com/category-example/1471337-text-blah-blah-2-blah-2010.html`

I'm trying to match only the numbers after the category-example/ ie. 1371937 and display them comma separated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is find the ID, then you should use `preg_match`, not `preg_replace`.

You've got lost of options for the pattern, the simplest being:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/category-example/1371937-text-blah-blah-blah-2012.html';
preg_match('/\d+/', $url, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Which simply finds the first bunch of numbers in the URL. This works for the examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you are matching against:

```
http://www.example.com/category-example/1371937-text-blah-blah-blah-2012.html
```

To get:

```
1371937
```

You would:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/category-example/1371937-text-blah-blah-blah-2012.html";
preg_match( "/[^\d]+(\d+)-/", $url, $matches );
$code = $matches[1];
```

.. which matches all non-numeric characters, then an unbroken string of numbers, until it reaches a '-'

Comment: No need to catch non-numbers before the part we're interested in. `preg_match( "/\/(\d+)-/", $url, $matches );` would also find the number on a website like example42.com